# ASP.NET: Illegal character '@' in '@Html.Raw' call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

At one point, I had no problem collecting the raw model by calling:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

but now I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected toke ILLEGAL
```

in Chrome and IE and it's point right at that '@' character

I've this (as suggested in another stackoverflow post):

```
var getRawLayoutData = function() { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); }
var rawModelData = getRawLayoutData();
```

and this (also suggested in another stackoverflow post):

```
var rawModelData = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))][0];
```

and nothing seems to work.

All I want to do is pass back some modified model data from the server to the client so I can react to the changing model data.

Any suggestions??

Comment: `@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))`

Comment: I haven't worked with razor extensively, but I generally do `@{ }` for block statements, `@()` seems a bit odd to me.. for clarification, this snippet is in a `cshtml` or `vbhtml` page that is being processed, right?

Comment: What file is this being done in? the cshtml?

Comment: @kformeck, please respond more timely.. I see two different errors going on here.. one is in your user-agent (browser) - which indicates that '@Html.Raw` isn't being processed... your browsers/user-agents should never see razor code.. they should only see the output; And the second error is in ASP.NET (your title is the only indication of this error).. this suggests your doing an `@Html.Raw` on a file/code that includes the code snippet you've provided us here...

Comment: @kformeck, are you attempting to load one view into another view (templating).. something like a partial view...

Comment: this code snippet is inside a JavaScript file (*.js), not a cshtml file.  I am not trying to embed a view inside another view, I am trying to crunch some numbers, retrieve some data from a database and respond to the changes in the model in the client.  All I need is to be able to retrieve the raw data passed back from the server.

Comment: .js file will not recognize `@Html` not in the past or present

Comment: I need to ask are you simply trying to call an action method client side then read the results?

Comment: BillRuhl:  That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I can direct the request to the controller, do the work needed but the issue I am having is reading the results from the client JavaScript.  Any suggestions?  Should I just embed a simple script into the cshtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try moving your script out of the .js file and putting it into a partial view.

use dynamic as your model type and make your partial view code something like this.

```
@model dynamic
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getRawLayoutData = function() { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); }
    var rawModelData = getRawLayoutData();
</script>
```

Then, where you're loading your javascript file in your main view, just use this instead

```
@Html.Partial("_Scipt", Model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Razor code only works in cshtml or vbhtml files. JS files are not preprocessed by Razor. Therefore, you were just sending the Razor code directly to the browser as JS (invalid JS). Short of just dumping all the JS code to the view, you can merely set the variable in view and then access it in your external JS file. I suggest using a namespace, though, so you don't pollute the global namespace and risk collisions with other JavaScript code.

**View**

```
<script>
    var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
    MyNamespace.RawModelData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
<script src="/path/to/external.js"></script>
```

Then, in your external JS, you can reference `MyNamespace.RawModelData` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));` instead.  That should fix your problem.  Looking back at my projects, this is the syntax I use and it doesn't give me any problems.

Comment: hey @jgabb, I think it's too early to tell whether this was the issue at all.. still, your suggestion would work under normal circumstances..

Comment: this didn't work, is this because I'm in a .js file?

Comment: Yes.  That is the reason.

Comment: jgabb: Thanks for clarifying; should I just embed a simple script into my cshtml file to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, just include your script in your cshtml file.  Remember not to use `@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));` in your js file though.. Do that in your cshtml file.